# using a texture on a custom geometry results in a webgl error "attempt to access out of range vertices"

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using this code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry.vertices.length = 0
geometry.faces.length = 0
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 32))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 32, 32))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 32, 0))
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(0, 1, 2, 3))

var wireMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color : 0xffffff,
  wireframe : true
})

var grassMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("grass.png") } )
var grassFaceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([grassMaterial])

scene.add(new THREE.Mesh( geometry, grassFaceMaterial ))
```

using `wireMesh` works okay:

[image: wiremesh]

but trying to use the textured mesh `grassFaceMaterial` as the material in the last line produces an error:

[image: error]

Comment: I found [this solution][1], hope it well help you .

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252764/how-to-create-a-custom-mesh-on-three-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably forgot to add the uvs.

```
geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push([
   new THREE.Vector2(0, 0 ),
   new THREE.Vector2( 0, 1 ),
   new THREE.Vector2( 1, 1 ),
   new THREE.Vector2( 1, 0)
] )
```