# Creating a custom mesh with THREE.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have attempted to create a custom mesh with Three.js using the following code:

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();

//geom verts

geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1,-1,-1));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,-1,-1));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1,0,-1));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1));

//faces
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1,2,3));
```

When I render the object, only one of the triangles renders (the first one). If someone could tell me what is wrong (or a guide to creating custom meshes without blender), that would be awesome.

Comment: maybe this helps as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252764/how-to-create-a-custom-mesh-on-three-js?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The face winding is different, for the first triangle its anti-clockwise and for the second triangle it is clock-wise. You can solve the problem in two different ways -

1) Provide the vertices in right order -

```
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1,3,2));
```

2) Render both side of the triangle.

```
var material = new MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `geom.computeFaceNormals();` after adding the vertices and faces.