# Rendering a polygon with input vertices in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have vertices(x,y,z coords) of a polygon as input. How can I render a polygon having these vertices in three.js?

There is [this](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/ShapeGeometry) documentation.But it seems to involve bezier. I need simple straight edged polygon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a polygon from vertices with the following code:

```js
var geom = new THREE.Geometry(); 
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(0,500,0);
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(0,500,500);

geom.vertices.push(v1);
geom.vertices.push(v2);
geom.vertices.push(v3);

geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
geom.computeFaceNormals();

var object = new THREE.Mesh( geom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );

scene.add(object);
```

Copy and paste this code in and then change x, y, and z coordinates of v1, v2, and v3 (or however many vertices you need) to the coordinates of your vertices.

Essentially, you are creating vertices using `THREE.Vector3` to supply the coordinates and then pushing them to the vertices property of an empty `THREE.Geometry()`;

Code is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9266861/9267033) answer

Comment: `THREE.Geometry` is removed from Three.JS

Comment: can any one help, how to draw polygon using THREE.BufferGeometry?

Answer (score 1):

`THREE.Geometry` is removed, try the following method

```js
    let coordinates = [
     {
       x : 1,
       y : 1,
       z: 10
     },
     {
       x : 2,
       y : 1,
       z: 10
     },
     {
       x : 2,
       y : 2,
       z: 10
     },
     {
       x : 1,
       y : 2,
       z: 10
     }
    ]
    let polyShape = new THREE.Shape(coordinates.map((coord) => new THREE.Vector2(coord.x, coord.y)))
    const polyGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(polyShape);
    polyGeometry.setAttribute("position", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(coordinates.map(coord => [coord.x, coord.y, coord.z]).flat(), 3))
    let polygon = new THREE.Mesh(polyGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "colorYOuWant", side: THREE.DoubleSide}))
    scene.add(polygon);
```

Comment: what is 'measurement' or how to define it?

Comment: Why does the polyGeometry need the 2D Shape at initialization when you seem to overwrite the points anyway with `setAttribute("position",..`? Or is this setAttribute not overwriting the points' positions?

Answer (score 0):

I also need this and while the answer of @Aakash helped me to start, setting the points in the ShapeGeometry was a problem

Just

- Build a `Shape` object with the 2D coordinates (`Vector2`)
- Build a ShapeGeometry from that Shape
- Build the `Mesh` from that Geometry and the `Material` you want
- rotate and scale the Mesh the way you want

Perfect example for it is https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes

Especially have a look at the `californiaShape` object and the `addShape` function

```
const californiaPts = [];

californiaPts.push( new THREE.Vector2( 610, 320 ) );
californiaPts.push( new THREE.Vector2( 450, 300 ) );
californiaPts.push( new THREE.Vector2( 392, 392 ) );
...
            
const californiaShape = new THREE.Shape( californiaPts );

addShape( californiaShape, ... );
```

---

```
function addShape( shape, extrudeSettings, color, x, y, z, rx, ry, rz, s ) {

    let geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shape );

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: color, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ) );
    mesh.position.set( x, y, z - 125 );
    mesh.rotation.set( rx, ry, rz );
    mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
    ...
}
```