# Threejs - How to build a polygon in 3D space from points

Tags: three.js, polygon

I guess it is an easy task, but I have flaws in my code or thoughts.

I want to create a polygon from some points that are all in the same plane and they are ordered (around the polygon) in a points array. But, depending on the points, the polygon does not look like it should.

I have created a [minimal repo](https://github.com/andymel123/t3-test) with just the code that builds the scene with the poly and an orthographic camera to view it.

```
npm i
npm run dev:test
```

I guess the important part is the way I build the polygon. Here is the code

```js
    function createPoly() {
    
        const points: readonly Vector3[] = [
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(4, 0, 0),
            // new Vector3(3, 0, 2),    // <- works
            new Vector3(4, 0, 4),
            // new Vector3(2, 0, 3),    // does not work
            new Vector3(0, 0, 4)
        ];
    
        let polyShape = new Shape(
            points.map((v3) => {
                const v2 = new Vector2(v3.x, v3.z);
                return v2;
            })
        );

        const polyGeometry = new ShapeGeometry(polyShape);
        polyGeometry.setAttribute(
            "position",
            new Float32BufferAttribute(
                points.map(v3 => [v3.x,v3.y,v3.z]).flat(),3)
        )    

        const polyMesh = new Mesh(
            polyGeometry,
            new MeshBasicMaterial({ 
                     color: 0x999999, 
                     side: DoubleSide })
        )
    
        return polyMesh;
    }
```

The 4 points of the square (x/z plane) work. But adding (2/0/3) is one example that behaves differently than I think.

`(3/0/2)` works, as long as I don't also add `(2/0/3)`.

Please give me a hint to my thought/code flaw.

Comment: You can create a working codesanbox and add the link to your question

Comment: The answer is in the threejs doc : https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my code above was the overwriting of the points in the ShapeGeometry (follow the link of @pirs above for more info).

Fixing it was as easy as removing that part. Creating the `Shape` with the 2D points is enough. When the `ShapeGeometry` is created from that `Shape` it is handled correctly. I had the code from another SO answer. See my answer there for some more info. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75557678/7869582

Here is the code from above without the faulty part

```js
    function createPoly() {
        
        const points: readonly Vector3[] = [
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(4, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(3, 0, 2),    // <- works
            new Vector3(4, 0, 4),
            new Vector3(2, 0, 3),    // <- works
            new Vector3(0, 0, 4)
        ];
    
        console.log("new poly", points.map(pos => `${pos.x.toFixed(2)}/${pos.y.toFixed(2)}/${pos.z.toFixed(2)}`));
        
        let polyShape = new Shape(
            points
                .map((v3) => {
                    const v2 = new Vector2(v3.x, v3.z);
                    return v2;
                })
        );
    
        const polyGeometry = new ShapeGeometry(polyShape);
    
        const polyMesh = new Mesh(
            polyGeometry,
            new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x999999, side: DoubleSide })
        )
        
        // I have to rotate the poly as I am working in the x/z plane
        polyMesh.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
    
        return polyMesh;
    }
```