# Can I skip the normal syntax and work with geometry buffers in three.js for faster performance?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to the area of geometry generation and manipulation and I'm planning on doing this on an intricate and large scale. I know the basic way of doing this is like it's shown [in the answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252764/how-to-create-a-custom-mesh-on-three-js).

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry(); 
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(0,500,0);
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(0,500,500);

geom.vertices.push(v1);
geom.vertices.push(v2);
geom.vertices.push(v3);

geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
geom.computeFaceNormals();

var object = new THREE.Mesh( geom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );

object.position.z = -100;//move a bit back - size of 500 is a bit big
object.rotation.y = -Math.PI * .5;//triangle is pointing in depth, rotate it -90 degrees on Y

scene.add(object);
```

But I do have experience with doing image manipulation working directly with a typed array image buffer on the GPU which is essentially the same thing as manipulating 3D points, since colors are essentially 3D points on a 2D grid (in the case of a buffer, flattened out to a 1D typed array) and I know just how much faster that kind of large scale manipulation is when processed with shaders on the GPU.

So I'm wondering if I can access the geometry in three.js directly as a typed array buffer. If so, I can use gpu.js to manipulate it on the GPU rather than CPU and boost performance exponentially.

Basically I'm asking if there's something like canvas's getImageData method for three.js geometry.

Comment: Please take a look at [the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/), specifically [`BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry) as associated objects. `BufferGeometry` is the way of the future, because `WebGL2Renderer` will _only_ support `BufferGeometry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ThJim01 mentioned in the comment, `THREE.BufferGeometry` is the way to go, but if you insist on using `THREE.Geometry` to initialize your list of triangles, you can use the [BufferGeometry.fromGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry.fromGeometry) function to generate the BufferGeometry from the Geometry you originally made.

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
// ... initialize verts and faces ...

// Initialize the BufferGeometry
var buffGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
buffGeom.fromGeometry(geometry);    

// Print the typed array for the position of the vertices
console.log(buffGeom.getAttribute('position').array);
```

Note that the resultant geometry will not have an index array and just be a list of disjointed triangles (as it was represented as in the first place!)

Hope that helps!